# How to append data to a JSON with a specific index in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, body-parser, writefile

I'm doing a basic 'Visitor Book' function. 
Users can submit a little form (with three inputs : name, msg and emoji).
I grab it with req.body in my router component. I'm using nodejs, with express and bodyparser.
I only want to store this data in a JSON, don't want any database involved here.
I'm in trouble with the **writeFile** method, using **'fs'** module.
It work but it push the new data outside the single-array of my JSON file.
Do you know if I can push in inside the array ? Like a .push method, but with *writeFile*/*appendFile*/*wathever* that works good with json files.
Here is my code :

app.post (router) :

```js
app.post('/visitorBook', async (req, res) => { 
    let formData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        msg: req.body.msg,
        emoji: req.body.emoji
    }
    try {
        console.log(req.body)
        let data = JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2);

        fs.writeFile("./views/scripts/dataVisitorBook.json", data, { { // dataVisitorBook.json is the storage file
            flag:'a' // this flag specify 'please append it' over 'please override file'
        }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log('error :', err)
        });


        res.redirect('/contact') 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('/visitorBook route error : ', error)
    }
})
```

My JSON :

```
[
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "msg": "test1",
        "emoji": "<i class='fas fa-hippo fa-3x'></i>"
    },
    {
        "name": "test2",
        "msg": "test2",
        "emoji": "<i class='fas fa-hippo fa-3x'></i>"
    }
]


{
  "name": "sd",
  "msg": "sd",
  "emoji": "<i class='fas fa-kiwi-bird fa-3x'></i>"
}
```

So the last one with "sd" in name and msg is the pushed one. The 2 other are manually written by me, for readFile tests.

I hope I provided all the information needed. Not used to post here...
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read from the existing file and parse it with `JSON.parse`, you will be able to actually use `Array.push` on it. And then you can write the stringified result back into the file:

```
fs.readFile("./views/scripts/dataVisitorBook.json", function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  let data = JSON.parse(data.toString('utf8'));

  data = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

  fs.writeFile("./views/scripts/dataVisitorBook.json", data, { { // dataVisitorBook.json is the storage file
      flag:'a' // this flag specify 'please append it' over 'please override file'
  }
  }, (err) => {
      console.log('error :', err)
  });
})
```

It might not be optimal though as it is likely to take more time as the file grows bigger.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks a lot for your help. It's precious.
I've archieved to make it work with reading it first. Tho, I did a slightly different code (at actually didn't need to parse the req.body because bodyparser did it for me lol.)
I'm posting the code as an answer in somes minutes

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your simple try But using some standards can be much better to you

There are some Standard JSON DBs for Node like :
[Simple JSON DB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-json-db)
[Node JSON DB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-db)
Also, you can try SQLite
I also try with a simple JSON file of use as DB. I faced lots of work and I have managed it too. So my advice is to use some standard libraries

Apart from it, you have to get the file data Parse it as JSON (Decoding) make changes and again serialize it and write into a file (Encoding).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Finally I used the readFileSync option. Tho, I'll see the libraries you got me for futur uses, definitly sounds useful. 
Just for a context, it's a really small website for my spouse, and I don't think we'll have more than... 30 submissions into that json ! But definitly thanks for your propositions

Answer (score 0):

***[SOLVED]***
Thanks to @***Divarrek*** , I've archieved to make it work.
So :

Read the file with fs.readFileSync. 
Then, I store this rawdata in a variable, while parsing it to JSON.
THen, I push it in the 'jsonBook' variable which is the json file temporarly made into a simple object-variable.
Then I write in the file with writeFile, passing the data as variable 'parsed', which contain a JSON.stringified version of my 'jsonBook'

```js
app.post("/visitorBook", async (req, res) => {
    let formData = {
        name: req.body.name,
        msg: req.body.msg,
        emoji: req.body.emoji,
    };
    try {
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("./views/scripts/dataVisitorBook.json");
        var jsonBook = JSON.parse(rawdata);
        let formDataParsed = JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2);
        jsonBook.push(formData);
        let parsed = JSON.stringify(jsonBook, null, 2);
        fs.writeFile("./views/scripts/dataVisitorBook.json", parsed, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("saved");
        });
        res.redirect("/contact");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("/visitorBook route error : ", error);
    }
});
```

I hope I was clear. Maybe I did some explanation error, I'm trying my best.